# Why didn't Holdo use auto-pilot?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

When

> Holdo sacrificed her life by ramming the First Order capital ship 
>  with the Raddus (using the light-speed trick),

why didn't she use auto-pilot? Or use a droid?

Comment: She couldn't send a droid because the Resistance treat droids like people

Comment: Fair comment. But you'd have thought that the rebels would have non-sentient no-brain droids (like toasters, washing machines or vacuum cleaners) who could work some levers after a certain time has passed.

Comment: I think the bigger question is why didnt the first order see this obvious tactic - oh I dont know - at any point during the ships slow rotation?

Comment: There's too many knobs, buttons and levers on the control panel. She only knew a few.

Comment: OOU - This seemed to me to be an attempt to loosely fictionalize the final moments of the [HMS Glowworm in WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Glowworm_(H92)#Final_battle), in order to produce a suitably heroic ending for the captain in question. The mechanics were a bit different (obviously), but the general idea was the same. If the captain didn't sacrifice themselves, it wouldn't have been heroic, just shrewd.

Comment: ...So if you see some detail that seems to have left the option for escape, then there must be a reason that wouldn't have worked, which perhaps wasn't depicted in the movie. People can speculate as to what that exact reason was, but all we really know is that there was one. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. very meta ! :) I'll join you and put my cynical hat on and say: This event was used by the screen-play writers to punish the toxic masculinity (alpha male, cocky, fly-boy) of poor Poe, by heaping the death of Holdo onto his shoulders.

Comment: I felt like the plot may have benefitted from a spy-within subplot. That way Holdo's actions in keeping their real destination a secret would make more sense (she _knows_ he's impetuous, it's risky to let him think there's no plan and then not expect him to come up with his own), _and_ they could have played it that she always intended to ram the FO fleet and didn't want to risk disclosing that in case it got back to them. But then a spy-within subplot might have been at odds with the hyperspace tracking subplot (why invent a new tracking system when you already have a spy on board).

Comment: @squire55 - I've seen that said a lot. To me what it looks like they are doing instead is setting Poe up to be a leader in the next movie, by showing him learn some lessons the hard way. That makes sense. Promoting the guy (in the next movie I'm assuming) and saying nice things about him behind his back after he organized a mutiny that likely got quite a few people killed isn't exactly a very feminist message.

Comment: To me, the real question is why did she wait until almost all rebellion ship are destroyed to perform her move.

Comment: More importantly, why didn't she leave the ship on autopilot in the first place?

Comment: @KyleStrand It isn't that easy to override autopilot safety mechanisms. You realize there wasn't enough time to override them, right?

Comment: @DarthVader I'm not sure what you mean. I'm asking why they didn't put the ship on autopilot as part of the evacuation.

Comment: Some sites suggest Holdos force sensitivity was essential in performing this manoeuvre.  That would explain why autopilot and droids were no option.

Answer (score 16):

## She didn't have time

By the time she decided to use The Raddus in a hyperspace kamikaze attack, the Resistance transports were already being wiped out. There would not have been time to set the auto-pilot and escape before more (perhaps all) of the transports were destroyed.

Before sacrificing herself, the point of staying behind was to ensure the First Order was distracted by the larger ship. The First Order might have noticed that the ship was on auto-pilot, but with a human pilot at the helm, she can navigate, make turns, and otherwise convince the First Order that The Resistance was still on board.

Comment: When she powers up the hyperspace engine and Hux is informed, he exclaims, "it's *empty*!". The First Order *knew* the Resistance was not on board.

Comment: @KyleStrand Only because DJ betrayed Finn and Rose by telling the First Order of the Resistance getting on transports. Without his betrayal, the bad guys would have been unaware of how empty the Raddus was

Comment: @DuffautM By the time Holdo makes her decision, the First Order has already started firing on the transports, so it's clear that this answer's claim that she can "convince the First Order that The Resistance [is] still on board" isn't correct.

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't follow you. When Holdo decided to stay on board, the First Order did not notice the smaller transports getting away. There is a scene where we clearly see her alone on deck watching the Resistance fleeing with a smile on her face while the Raddus was the only target, showing that her plan worked. The next scene is the betrayal of DJ and a First Order officer claiming that after verifications, he was telling the truth. Next scene was the turbolaser aiming and shooting at the transports vessels and Holdo dropping her smile.

Comment: @DuffautM You're right-- I didn't notice when responding to your comment that the second paragraph of this answer is talking about her decision to stay on board, not her decision to turn the ship around and jump to hyperspace.

Comment: I don't buy it. The ships were all pretty much flying straight and level until she started the about face--not exactly clever maneuvering that needed be maintained. And how long could it take to set the autopilot?

Answer (score 5):

**There were no transports left.**

By the time the First Order stopped firing on the *The Raddus* and started destroying the smaller transports, there were no other transports aboard the cruiser because they had already been evacuated.

Comment: And no escape pods?

Comment: Indeed. And surely these ships have sophisticated auto-pilots. Set ramming target to FO, then hop into an escape pod.

Comment: @squire55 A sophisticated autopilot would not allow itself to be programmed to do something that would violate the precepts of being a good spacer, let alone something that would lead to the destruction of the ship. It simply wouldn't be an option in the software, because it isn't safe.

Comment: @TJL Surely, "being a good spacer" is saving lives. In this example Holdo was. So a sophisticated auto-pilot ought to have special overrides.

Comment: @squire55 No, in this example Holdo is ramming another vessel - she's taking lives, not saving them.

Comment: @squire55 A sophisticated auto-pilot would not have such special overrides. It would have safety measures in place. A simple one would be like cruise control. You set the speed/course, and you keep going until you get there. It would have few, if any, safety measures. With a sophisticated auto-pilot, I would doubt that it would be able to understand what a good spacer is. Even so, being a good spacer would not mean "ramming another ship at lightspeed". Holdo was being more of a "heroic captain" than a "good spacer". If you want an auto-pilot that understands what a good spacer is, get a droid.

Comment: *it wouldn't have such overrides without a great deal of trouble to go through in order to activate them

Answer (score -4):

Maybe autopilots don't exist?

I say this because I'm pretty sure I recall a debate on the First Order bridge where someone says that there's no point paying attention to The Raddus because "there's only one person on board". How could they know that, if autopilots are a possibility (in universe)?

Comment: Scanning for signs of life?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, yeah, possibly.

Comment: Before Holdo decides to turn the ship around, she's just walking around the bridge, not touching any of the controls. So clearly the ship can keep flying without a pilot physically piloting it.